# How to expire a cookie in 30 minutes using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

How to Expire a Cookie in 30 min ? I am using a jQuery cookie.
I am able to do something like this.

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 1 });
```

This is for 1 day. But how can we set expiry time to 30 min.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

30 minutes is `30 * 60 * 1000` miliseconds. Add that to the current date to specify an expiration date 30 minutes in the future.

```
 var date = new Date();
 var minutes = 30;
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
 $.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: date });
```

Comment: Also for works for the newer incarnation: [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

Answer (score 6):

If you're using **jQuery Cookie** (https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/), you can use decimal point or fractions.

As one day is `1`, one minute would be `1 / 1440` (there's 1440 minutes in a day).

So 30 minutes is `30 / 1440 = 0.02083333`.

Final code:

```js
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 30 / 1440, path: '/' });
```

I've added `path: '/'` so that you don't forget that the cookie is set on the current path. If you're on `/my-directory/` the cookie is only set for this very directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues getting the above code to work within cookie.js. The following code managed to create the correct timestamp for the cookie expiration in my instance.

var inFifteenMinutes = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 15 * 60 * 1000);

This was from the [FAQs for Cookie.js](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#expire-cookies-in-less-than-a-day)