# How do you setup a cookie which expires after 5mins in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am unsure on how to setup a cookie on the following code : http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/GmLVj/8/

I want it to show for 5mins when logged in and then if I press on log out it would destroy the cookie.

Can anyone help??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to expire a cookie in 30 minutes using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830246/how-to-expire-a-cookie-in-30-minutes-using-jquery)

Answer (score 5):

For 5 mins you need to modify it to : -

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (5 * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: date });
```

You have set it to 30 minutes now.

Comment: you can add the cookie handling into the method like http://jsfiddle.net/GmLVj/9/

Comment: @Jayendra you mean 5 minutes, not 30! :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need jquery for this (see [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) for a tutorial).

Anyway there's a plugin called [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), which can help you with this.

To create a cookie with a lifetime of 5 minutes:

```
var expires = new Date();
expires.setMinutes( expires.getMinutes() + 5 ); // Create a date 5 minutes from now

// The path parameter is needed to make this cookie valid across the whole page
$.cookie('login_id', 'cafed00d', {expires: expires, path: '/'});
```

To destroy said cookie:

```
$.cookie('login_id', null);
```

Note that if this is a secure login, you should have server-side checks in place, because users can inspect your JavaScript and modify cookies at will.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). The plugin allows you to set an expiry date like this:

```
{expires: date}
```

where date is a date object. In your case you should do (for 5 minutes):

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (5 * 60 * 1000));
```

Answer (score 1):

5 minutes is 5 * 60 * 1000 miliseconds.

```
var date = new Date();
 var minutes = 5;
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
 $.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: date });
```