# Setting cookie values with jquery and slidetoggle

Tags: jquery, toggle, jquery-cookie

I'm using jquery's slideToggle and carhartl's cookie plugin (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to remember the state of whether a div is toggled open or not. I have it working and remembering the position, but I'd like to set a 1 day expiry time for the cookie rather than having it last until the end of session as default.

I can set the expiry time ok when the toggle state is open but as soon as it's closed I'm struggling to see where to set the expiry time. Can anyone help?

Thanks :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<style>
#billboardButton {
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    color:#666;
    padding:3px;
    width:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var cook= $.cookie('billboardStatus', 'true', {expires: 1});

    if(cook=='false') {

        $('#billboard').hide();

        $("#billboardButton").css("backgroundColor", "#e1e1e1").text('Open Ad');        

    } else {

    $('#billboard').show();

        $("#billboardButton").text('Close Ad');
    }

    $('#billboardButton').on('click', function() {

        $('#billboard').stop().slideToggle('normal', function(){

            $("#billboardButton").css("backgroundColor", $(this).is(':not(:visible)') ? "#e1e1e1" : "").text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Close Ad' : 'Open Ad');

            $.cookie('billboardStatus', $(this).is(':visible'));

        });

    });

}); // End document ready
</script>
<div id="test" style="width:970px;margin:20px auto;">
    <div id="billboardButton">Close Ad</div>
    <div id='billboard' style='width:970px; height:250px;background-color:#0C9;'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830246/how-to-expire-a-cookie-in-30-minutes-using-jquery

Comment: So what you're saying is you need to establish a conditional statement within the `.slideToggle()` to evaluate the visibility of a div and react upon that, right?

Comment: I know how it works @cptnk, I just can't see where to put it ;-)

Comment: I already have that @Ohgodwhy, I just need to set the cookie expiry time but can't figure it out

Comment: I see, sorry for that.

Comment: can´t you just set the expire time? $.cookie("billboardStatus" { expires: date });

Comment: I have done that @cptnk, but every time this line is run…

`$.cookie('billboardStatus', $(this).is(':visible'));` the expiry gets reset to end of session. I need to add it to this line I think but not sure how.

Comment: you do need a date object

Comment: Where would I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself :-)

I added an if exists statement to the beginning to check for the cookie, and also added managed to discover where to add the {expires: 1} parameter to the slideToggle code purely by chance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    if($.cookie('billboardStatus')) {

        var cook = $.cookie('billboardStatus');

    } else {

        var cook = $.cookie('billboardStatus', 'true', {expires: 1});

    }

    //var cook= $.cookie('billboardStatus');

    if(cook=='false') {

        $('#billboard').hide();

        $("#billboardButton").css("backgroundColor", "#e1e1e1").text('Open Ad');        

    } else {

    $('#billboard').show();

        $("#billboardButton").text('Close Ad');
    }

    $('#billboardButton').on('click', function() {

        $('#billboard').stop().slideToggle('normal', function(){

            $("#billboardButton").css("backgroundColor", $(this).is(':not(:visible)') ? "#e1e1e1" : "").text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Close Ad' : 'Open Ad');

            $.cookie('billboardStatus', $(this).is(':visible'), {expires:1});

        });

    });

}); // End document ready
```