# Display fancybox on page load per session

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, fancybox, session-cookies

Using fancyBox v2 and jQuery Cookie plugins.

Code:

```
var check_cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');
if(check_cookie == null){
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
$("#hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');
}
```

It works. But I want, when I close site or browser and come back, display fancybox again. Tried this but not working:

```
var check_cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');

if(check_cookie == null){

$("#hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click'), {
'onComplete' : function() {
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
}
});
}
```

Checked via DevTools, get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) on 42. 

42. line:

    });
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

set time frame to cookie while assigning, lets say for 30 mins

```
var check_cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');
if(check_cookie == null){
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 30 * 60 * 1000 });
$("#hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');
}
```

refer below link for ref..

[How to expire a cookie in 30 minutes using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830246/how-to-expire-a-cookie-in-30-minutes-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple syntax error. `onComplete` is an API option of fancybox, therefore it goes inside the fancybox function like

```
var check_cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');
if (check_cookie == null) {
    $("#hidden_link").fancybox({
        'onComplete': function () {
            $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
        }
    }).trigger('click');
}
```