# Change the cookie experation time to 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a cookiescript, works great.
I would like to have the experation time after 5 minutes.
How can I do this?

expires: 30   = **30 days?**

## EDIT

```
cookie_popup = (function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var minutes = 5;
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));

    if ($.cookie('cookie_popup') == undefined) {
        $('.cookie-popup-wrap').fadeIn(600);
        $.cookie('cookie_popup',true,{ expires: date });
    };

    $('#closepopup').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.cookie-popup-wrap').fadeOut(600);
    });
});

setTimeout(function() {
    cookie_popup();
}, 2000);

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
        cookie_popup();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's said in [**$.cookie documentation**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

> **expires:**
>
> Define lifetime of the cookie. Value can be a Number which will be interpreted as days from time of creation or a Date object. If omitted, the cookie becomes a session
>   cookie.

So you'll have to pass Date object there. For example:

```
var expireDate   = new Date();
var minutesToAdd = 5; 
expireDate.setMinutes(expireDate.getMinutes() + minutesToAdd);
$.cookie('cookie_popup', true, { expires: expireDate });
```

Comment: thanks, I have edited my post, is this correct now? sorry, I don't know coding.

Comment: This particular part seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Possible dublicate: [How to expire a cookie in 30 minutes using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830246/how-to-expire-a-cookie-in-30-minutes-using-jquery)

```
var date = new Date();
var minutes = 5;
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: date });
```