# JS cookie expires in mins not days

Tags: javascript, cookies

Here is what I have I need my cookie to expire after like 5 mins how would I do that vs right now I have it set to 30 days

```
av_setCookie = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var is_legal = $(e.currentTarget).attr('rel');

$.cookie('is_legal', is_legal, {
    expires: 30,
    path: '/'
});

if (is_legal == "yes") {
    av_closeModal();
    $(window).off('resize');
} else {
    av_showRegret();
}
```

};

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to expire a cookie in 30 minutes using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830246/how-to-expire-a-cookie-in-30-minutes-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a date object as parametter :

```
$.cookie('is_legal', is_legal, {
    expires: new Date().setTime(new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 5),
    path: '/'
});
```