# Add 10 minutes expired time on cookie in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

i have this command line in php for set a cookie.

```
        document.cookie="<?php echo $_POST["setcookie"]; ?>"+"domain=.adidas.it;path=/";
```

I want to add 10 minutes expired time, who can help me? thanks

Comment: See [How to expire a cookie in 30 minutes using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1830263/4535200)

Answer (score 1):

There is a PHP function to set a cookie

```
setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

In your case

```
$name = "yourname";
$value = "yourvalue";
$expire = time() + (60*10);
$domain = ".adidas.it";
$path = "/";
setcookie($name,$value,$expire,$path,$domain);
```