# Jquery - cookies set expired date for 1 day

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to learn about cookies in js, followed one tutorial and everything went smoothly but I wish to set expired date for 1 day. If I just write {expired: 1} It. somehow is 22h,
I found on forum example like :

```
var date = new Date();
            var expired = '';
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + 1);
            expired += date.toGMTString();
```

But It doesn't really work for me and doesn't show cookies at all when I try to do

```
{expires: expired}
```

Can you guys give me some hints how to set it for 24hours?

```
$('#accept').click(function () {
        if (!$('.change-message--on-click').is('hide--first')) {
            $('.change-message--on-click').removeClass('hide--second');
            $('.change-message--on-click').addClass('hide--first');

            var date = new Date();
            var expired = '';
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + 1);
            expired += date.toGMTString();

            $.cookie('choosen-Accept', 'yes', {expires: 1 });
        }
    return false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding hours to Javascript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050720/adding-hours-to-javascript-date-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

24 hours is `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` milliseconds. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830263/7678419)

If you need add few days to date of expires cookie you should use number

```
$.cookie('choosen-Accept', 'yes', {
   expires: 1
});
```

If you need custom time you should create date and pass it to `expired`

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
$.cookie('choosen-Accept', 'yes', {
    expires: date
});
```

To make sure you can look at this [source code](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js#L62) line 6

**Full example**

```
  $('#accept').click(function() {
    if (!$('.change-message--on-click').is('hide--first')) {
      $('.change-message--on-click').removeClass('hide--second');
      $('.change-message--on-click').addClass('hide--first');

      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

      $.cookie('choosen-Accept', 'yes', {
        expires: date
      });
    }
    return false
  });
```

Comment: It works, I guess:)! thank you so much, but could you only tell me, before in expires, was written particular date and hours when session is expired, now it is "at the end of session", is it normal and will it be expired after 24h or I did something wrong?
Plus with var expired = date.toGMTString(); line it didn't work

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. Could you please more information about what you want to do ?

Comment: I wish to set expires date for 24hours, if I write above code with line `var expired = date.toGMTString();`, it doesn't work, if without this line, It does work. However when I check it in console log, it shows number 1538574304616, I assume that if before `{expires:1}` meant one day(or rather weird 22h), then if I pass this gigantic number, it will mean almost forever, no?

Comment: I expanded my example for you. If you use `{expires:1}` your cookies will expires after 1 day. If you need use custom time you need to use `{expires: data}` when type of data is Date

Comment: You can look at [source code](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js.). `line: 62`

Comment: oki I got it now and it works:) Thanks friend for your help and patience:)